# What format polygon does D3plus largest rectangle require?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, polygon, d3plus

I found an interesting demo of how to find the largest rectangle in an irregular shaped polygon [here](http://d3plus.org/blog/behind-the-scenes/2014/07/08/largest-rect/) using D3plus.

I'm trying to recreate this for a polygon I'm working on but currently the code is not working. It seems to runs endlessly. The code I'm using is as follows:

```js
d3.csv("data/polyPoints.csv", function(error, polyPoints) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  
  // coerce string values to numbers
  polyPoints.forEach(function(d) {
   d3.keys(d).forEach(function(k) {
    d[k] = +d[k]
   })
  });
  
  // settings for geom.largestRect
  var rectOptions = {
   angle: 0,
   maxAspectRatio: 5,
   nTries: 1

  };
  
  console.log(rectOptions);
  console.log(polyPoints);

   var lRect = d3plus.geom.largestRect(polyPoints, rectOptions);
  console.log(lRect); 
  
});
```

I suspect my polygon is not in the correct format.

**Update**

I'm making progress. My original polygon object was taken from a csv and created an array of arrays of key value pairs (e.g. {"x": 0 "y": 1},{"x": 2, "y": 1}....)

I converted this to an array of arrays (e.g. [[1,0],[2,0]....])

Now the code is running but the output is defining rectangles that cross the boundary of the original polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone working with this. The largestRect docs are https://d3plus.org/docs/#largestRect and can be run with the following code.

```
const d3p = require('d3plus');
const polygon = [[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]...]

const rectOptions = {
    maxAspectRatio: 5,
    nTries: 20
};

let lRect = d3p.largestRect(rdp, rectOptions);
```

The algorithm used is an approximation and random points inside the polygon are chosen to do calculations from. Because of this the edges of the box won't always be touching the edge but should be "close enough".

The options.tolerance value might affect this as well but I haven't played around with it much. This is a pretty old question but hopefully it helps someone.